# Which method is better for offline storage in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, offline-caching, shared-objects

I am Working in Mobile application In Which I need To store data in offline. I've searched in the web and found three methods to store data offline.

1. Shared Object
2. SQlLite Database
3. Store in Binary File

Now, I like to know that which method is good for offline storage in flex. If I like to store large data like video, audio and also text in offline storage.

And why is that method is better for storing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not much used shared object, But i can tell the use of each options

1. Shared Object used to store the data as object.
2. SQlLite Database is used for storing textual data.
3. Binary file is is more useful to you because it performs well and store large amount of          data.

Comment: How can i use all method at the same time? I like to use only one method for storing data

Comment: no i am not saying that you can use binary file. I just describe all three options.

Comment: SQlLite database can not store Video, Audio Data??

Comment: no SQlLite can't store video, audio. you have to use binary file

Comment: it is recomended that you should store file sizes greater than 500 KB in filesystem instead of storing those in sqlite.You can save the fiile path in sqlite database

Comment: THIS IS WRONG! You CAN store whatever data you want inside SQLLite, using BLOB!